# Quorum-dev-quickstart, Besu, Waiting for network to be up

Tags: docker, hyperledger, quorum

[image]

on Ubuntu 20.04, 4vCPU, 16G RAM, GCP -- after installing Node, NPM, docker-io, docker-compose and docker compose plugin,

I just ran the command:

```
npx quorum-dev-quickstart --clientType besu --outputPath ./quorum-test-network --monitoring default --privacy false --orchestrate true --quorumKeyManager false
```

It is stuck at "Waiting for network to be up...." This is for the 5th time or so.. Once I waited for more than an hour for it to finish, but it kept going...

((hyperledger/besu:22.7.1 seems to be continuously restarting... ))

TOP:
[image]

DOCKER IMAGES:
[image]

DOCKER PS:
[image]

Comment: If the diagnostic information you've included is useful, it will be much more readable in plain-text format.  It looks like you've resolved your issue, but for future questions, please avoid attaching screen shots of terminal windows.

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with GCP creating default user with id 1001. The quorum docker containers expect user 1000 to be used. Logging in as user 1000 solves the issue.